# Model for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, model

I just started with ASP.NET MVC 1.0. I've read through some tutorials but I don't have any good ideas on how to build my model.

I've been experimenting with LINQ to SQL. Can't say I like it that much, but I'll give it a try. I prefer using SQL Stored Procedures, but it doesn't seem to work very good together with the optional parameters in my stored procedures.

The project is a prototype, but I would like to start with a good design right away.

The database will probably contain around 50 tables and stored procedures will be used for all queries and updates. Some procedures will also return multiple results. How would the best way to design this model?

All and any ideas are welcome. Should I even use LINQ to SQL? Should I design my stored procedures to only return one result? I feel a little bit lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use stored procedures with LINQ.  You simply need to replace the autogenerated statements on your entities with your stored procs.  Look at the properties for the entity (table) in the designer to change these.  Your stored procedures won't be able to return multiple results as they need to map onto a collection of either one of your entities or an autogenerated entity, i.e, onto a collection of a single class.

Having said all that, I'd give it a go without using stored procedures.  The LINQ code is fully parameterized so you already have this benefit.  You'll find that LINQ allows you to easily build up queries alleviating your need for the optional parameters in your stored procs and, likely, resulting in more efficient queries as you don't need to build extra logic into your query to handle the optional parameters.  Once you start using LINQ I think you'll find that the power and expressiveness in the code will make you forget about using your stored procedures.

You may still have a need for stored procs or table-valued functions for complex queries -- that's ok.  If they map onto an existing entity, you can simply drag the proc/function onto the entity in the designer and you get a nice method on your data context that runs your SQL and returns collections of that entity.  If not, I often create a view for the proc/function schema, use that as an entity, and attach the proc/function to it.

Answer (score 0):

May I ask why you need to use stored procedures for this project?  They have almost no value today if you are working with a modern database.  Parameterized SQL using a good ORM will give you the same cached execution plans and security benefits that you are looking for with stored procedures.

I would recommend [NHibernate](https://www.hibernate.org/343.html) because it's a far better way to achieve persistence ignorance.  And IMHO this is the goal of anyone designing a model.  You should be thinking object first instead of data first.

The best resource around is a screencast series by [Steve Bohlen](http://unhandled-exceptions.com/blog/index.php/about/) "[The summer of nhibernate](http://www.summerofnhibernate.com/)"

Also [LINQ to NHibernate](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/07/26/nhibernate-linq-1.0-released.aspx) is available and works great for any dynamic query that you might need to write.

The only pain you will notice with NHibernate is the XML, but if you really enjoy the ORM you could write a fluent interface instead using [FNH](http://fluentnhibernate.org/).

I found NHibernate to be the best tool around for modeling a domain because your objects are 100% infrastructure free and this allows you to do anything you want with them without having to worry about the database.  Also if you are into unit testing of any kind this will make your life much easier :P

**Edit**

Part of the reason I replied to your question is that I have built many a system using stored procedures and found to regret that decision later.  But in my situation I had a requirement by a dba so I couldn't step away from the norm.

If you are already looking at LINQ to SQL I would simply encourage you to look at NHibernate as another great option to achieve the goal of persistence ignorance.

When I got away from thinking about the problem data first it allowed me to work at a much higher level and take advantage of the .net platform for solving problems.  TSQL has its place but if you are writing an application and want to maintain it - try to think about how your domain objects will work together in memory first.

Comment: Personally I find nHibernate much less compelling now that LINQ exists. LINQ-to-SQL can be a perfectly good ORM for a lot of people

Comment: Sure, but you can do the exact same thing now that NHibernate has a LINQ provider with the added benefit that you can work with more complex mappings.  For example: if you have parent data in a separate table from the child data nhibernate is cool with this.  But with LINQ to SQL you must have everything in one table.  So for situations like this where you need more flexibility or you know the complexity of the model (or database) is large - IMHO NHibernate is the better tool for the job.

Comment: It's only useful if it's useful to you. If you never need those advanced features, then its just another library you have to keep up with. I would probably never add it to a project until it was obvious that it would be useful. Note that I feel the same way about databases. I think for many corporate .net projects (mostly glorified CMS's and process tools) It's probably overkill. I'm not saying it's bad or anything, it's just LINQ is already there and well documented and well supported on blogs and SO. So if a newbie asked me which one to go with, I'd probably say LINQ

Comment: I prefer to use stored procedures. It's a good way to let the database expert to concentrate on database operations and the programmer on code. I like writing LINQ queries in code as little as like writing SQL strings in code. Even worse I think it is to have some queries in code and some in stored procedures. I prefer to have all SQL collected in one place and not in code.

Comment: I do agree that stored procs are evil, Know whats even better? Not using SQL servers at all. Try CouchDB.

Comment: No one said you couldn't include your SQL team in the conversation. In fact I profile any new application using an ORM and review each query with them to ensure the tables have valid indexes / etc. But to ask anyone to write a stored procedure is simply a waste of time and money - period